# How do I select all text of the user control WebKitBrowser in Webkit.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, webkit, webbrowser-control

There is a method `SelectedText` in WebKitBrowser, however, no `SelectAll`. Is there a way for me to do something like the following:

```
string GetAllTextOfBrowserAsPlainText(WebKitBrowser webKitBrowser)
{
    webKitBrowser.SelectAll(); //Doesn't exist
    return webKitBrowser.SelectedText;
}
```

My goal is to render a webpage entirely (including styling) and then copy the content of a webpage in plane text as if I used copy/paste in my browser.

Getting the `InnerText` or working with the HTML directly is not an option.

I have tried the WebBrowser UC with `WebBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand` to capture the text however I couldn't get the styling to work properly. I am now trying WebKit, and I am so close to getting what I want. Any help? Does `ExecCommand("SelectAll",...)` exist for WebKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding javascript to the end of the downloaded html. Calling js from code was tricky, since it seems like WebKit.Net has trouble with doing this directly. The following is not my final production code, but will help anybody in the same spot along the way:

```
private WebKitBrowser _browser = ...;
private string _selectAllCopyScript = "<script>document.execCommand('SelectAll', false, null);document.execCommand('Copy', false, null); </script>";
private string _plain = ...;

Form1()
{
    ...
    _browser.DocumentCompleted += OnDocumentCompleted;
}

private string GetAllTextOfBrowserAsPlainText(String html)
{
    _browser.Focus();
    _browser.DocumentText = html + _selectAllCopyScript; //Calls OnDocumentCompleted when done
}

private void OnDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _plain = Clipboard.GetText();
    Clipboard.Clear();
}
```

I wish I found a solution which didn't have to use the clipboard. The final plain text copied html is stored in `_plain`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using WebClient

```
       using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
      string mystring= wc.DownloadString("http://yoururl.com");
```

Comment: Thank you, however, this downloads the HTML of the URL. I am not looking for the HTML, I want the displayed content as plain text. If you go to a webpage in your favorite web browser then hit Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C then go to, say, Notepad, and hit Ctrl+V then the content of Notepad is what I want as a string. That is, I want the style and any script to be applied then get the plane text of the displayed content of a web page.

Comment: consider using something like htmlagilitypack to get the text part alone from html

Comment: I have actually tried this exact same code, alas, to no avail. It doesn't handle styling. It just rips it out. I want the style to be processed, i.e., all the display and hide features of the style should be applied before I extract the text. I am pretty sure I have to use a functioning browser UC, then get the plain text from it.